# How to find a usb drive using it's serial number?

Tags: usb, usbserial

Using a USB flash drive serial number I need to be able to find it so I can save a file to it without having to click because I'm using keystrokes on it.

The reason is, I am making code that will copy someone's ip address (just for myself to learn) and paste it into a .txt file but I need to save onto a flash drive not the desktop and I can't just click on it because it needs to be automated with keystrokes.

I tried naming the .txt file the name of the serial number of the flash drive kinda how you can name it E:\ and it will save to that flash drive, I was hoping it would save to the flash drive, but it didn't instead it just named the .txt file the serial number.

Comment: So can you show us what you have tried so far? See [ask]. Also might be worth having a look at [tour].

Comment: Ok I'll check those out, but so far when I'm in notepad I press alt+s to save and it automatically tries to save it to one drive so I need to save it on the USB drive but if someone else has a different USB drive in it gets called something different, so I can't save it through the name, but the serial number should stay the same, I tried naming the file the serial number but that's about it.